# How to parse JSONArray in android without key

Tags: android, json

I have a response from the server like this:

```
[
  "test1",
  [
    "test2",
    "test3",
    "test4"
  ]
]
```

I try to parse this response to JSONObject but when log ***jsonObject.toString()***, It doesn't show anything. So I just parse response with JSONArray and want to show in RecyclerView:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
     dataModel.setId(i);
     dataModel.setWord(jsonArray[i]);
     temp.add(dataModel);
}
```

but I have error on ***jsonArray[i]***. I can from the beginning, Do like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
response = jsonArray.toString().replaceAll(" []" ", "");
String[] words = response.split(",");
```

And with a for loop, Added data to RecyclerView. But if a word in response contain **{"}**, this way remove it.
How pare this json?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for each element whether it is an array or a String and parse it dynamically.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     //here check if jsonArray[i] is String or not
     //if its an array then do 
     // JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(jsonArray[i]);

}
```

Comment: How to check jsonArray[i] is String or not?

Comment: You can use `Object a =  jsonArray[i]; a instanceOf String ` https://www.baeldung.com/java-instanceof

Comment: this way show me an error: Array type expected; found: 'org.json.JSONArray'

Answer (score 0):

Though the JSON is valid, it has a weird structure. I am not sure if you can fit this JSON in a consistent data model.

Looks like the first element is a `String` and the second element is another list. Hence you could do something as follows.

```
List<String> allElements = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    try {
        // Try to parse it to an array
        JSONArray elementArr = new JSONArray(jsonArray[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < elementArr.length(); j++) {
            // I hope the nested JSON array is not messed up!! 
            allElements.add(elementArr[j]);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // The element is not an array, hence add it to the list directly
        allElements.add(jsonArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Finally, `allElements` should have all the strings that you want.